# Can we print an ' A ' with ' * '' using for loop in C#

Tags: c#

I want to print the letter "A" on screen. The letter should be built using the asterix symbol (*). For instance in a console application.

Can this be done in simple way using for loop.

For example:

```
  **
*    *
*    *
******
*    *
*    *
```

**EDIT :**

Answers below are totally unrelated to the OP, but ***Very Intriguing, Knowledgeable, and Meaningful***

Comment: I think he wants to know how to automatically generate the letter "A" on screen (console app) consisting out of a bunch of ***** symbols. Something similar to ASCII art.

Comment: @Christophe : yes that's what i want and BoltClock i know it aint necessary, but can this be done using a simple for loop

Comment: BTW why are the downvotes ?? , please explain

Comment: @Pankaj: I think the question was pretty unclear. Had to stare at it a while before I got what you wanted (maybe that's just me). I submitted an edit request already.

Comment: I don't understand. The title reads as clear as it can be. Still some people didn't gave it a thought and downvoted without understanding the post.

Comment: I downvoted. I couldn't understand the question. Rather than blaming us for being stupid, you should learn to be more explicit when asking.

Comment: @David, No offences or any reference to being stupid. It was just that you didnt gave time to understanding what was asked. Read the title to anyone and if he says he couldn't understand whats being asked here, i will close the question ASAP

Comment: @genesis: Thx that is a better looking A than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible way of doing that is to write the letter as you would expect to print it in a text file like this:

```
001100
100001
100001
111111
100001
100001
```

Save this in a A.txt file. Then do a function that would print this by iterating on pattern you defined in the corresponding letter file.

```
public void PrintChar(char charToPrint)
{
    string filename = string.Format("{0}.txt", charToPrint);

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        string line;

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            foreach (char c in line.ToCharArray())
            {
                Console.Write(c == '1' ? '*' : ' ');
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This solution is not flexible at all, but if you want only to print only a few letters of the alphabet it works pretty well :)

Edit: A better idea would be to name the file after its ASCII code so you can also print lower case characters. Windows filesystem thinks A.txt and a.txt are the same.

Answer (score 4):

One possible way, although a bit of work and maybe not suited for someone just starting to lean C# is the following approach:

1. Take the letter you want to print and generate and image of it. Letter can be colored, but preferable just black and white.

   For example:

[image: the letter A]

2. Load the image (Image & Bitmap types)
3. Convert it to grayscale
4. Loop through every pixel and determine if you are dealing with a white or black (or other non-white) pixel. Here's your for-loop.
5. Print out symbols (space, *...etc.) depending on the pixel's color.

This is similar to the following approach on CodeProject for generating ASCII art.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/ascii_art_with_c_.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's what you want but you can create a 2D array and print it's content using nested for loops:

```
var asciiArtA = new [,]
                {
                    {' ', ' ', '*', ' ', ' '},
                    {' ', '*', ' ', '*', ' '},
                    {' ', '*', ' ', '*', ' '},
                    {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*'},
                    {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'},
                    {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'},
                    {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'}
                };

for (int i = 0; i < asciiArtA.GetLength(0); ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < asciiArtA.GetLength(1); ++j)
    {
        Console.Write(asciiArtA[i,j]);
    }
 Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Will print:

```
  *
 * *
 * *
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
```

Comment: I think you mean Console.Write(asciiArtA[i][j]);

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the 'for loop' idea, you can print/render ascii text using another library via PInvoke such as [figlet](http://www.figlet.org/).

See it in action at http://asciiset.com/figletserver.html. The following was generated using the **courb** font

```
          ##  ##                         ##    ##  
## #       #   #         #   #            #     #  
 # #  ###  #   #   ##    # # #  ##  ####  #   ###  
 ### ####  #   #  ## #   # # # ## #  # #  #  ## #  
 # # ##    #   #  ## #   # # # ## #  #    #  ## #  
## #  ### ### ###  ##     # #   ##  ###  ###  ####
```